# How to compare two objects with random constructors

Tags: java, random, compare

I made these 2 objects:

```
Fighter Lucas = new Fighter(Statistics.punchStrength, 
Statistics.movementSpeed, Statistics.reflex);
Opponent Simon = new Opponent(Statistics.punchStrength2, 
Statistics.movementSpeed2, Statistics.reflex2);
```

I want to make them "fight" by comparing their random variables, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: you wanna match Lucas punch strength with Simon punch strength or with any other variable

Comment: i want to match punchStrength with punchStrength2 etc. and then make one of them "win" by calculating average value of 3 variables.

Comment: And what is the problem ? You don't know how to compare instances, how to compare multiple values or to find an algorithm matching those 3 values ? It's seems you didn't try much for know.

Comment: Please read (and apply) the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `Fighter` class should have a method `attack(Opponent)`

```
class Figher{
  // ..
  public void attack(Opponent opponent){
    int opponentMaxDamage = calculateHitpointsBy(opponent);
    int damageByOpponent = opponent.defend(this, opponentMaxDamage);
    this.lifePoints-=damageByOpponent;
  }

  public boolean isAlive(){
    return 0< this.lifePoints;
  }
  // ..
}
```

and your Opponent class should have a method `defend(Fighter)`

```
class Opponent{
  // ..
  public void defend(Figher fighter, int maxAttackDamage){
    int myDamage = reduceDamage(fighter,int maxAttackDamage);
    int attackerDamage = calculateAttackerDamage(fighter);
    this.lifePoints-=myDamage ;
  }

  public boolean isAlive(){
    return 0< this.lifePoints;
  }
  // ..
}
```

This gives you the possibility to add more complex calculations for the life points later. Eg.: the actual damage an attacker can do to the opponent may depend on the equipment she wears. The same may be true for the damage the opponent receives.

The method  `isAlive()` could be extracted to a common base class...

You use it this way:

```
Fighter Lucas = new Fighter(Statistics.punchStrength, Statistics.movementSpeed, Statistics.reflex);
Opponent Simon = new Opponent(Statistics.punchStrength2, Statistics.movementSpeed2, Statistics.reflex2);

// fight
while(Lucas.isAlive()&&Simon.isAlive())
   Lucas.attack(Simon);

// report winner
if(Lucas.isAlive())
   System.out.println("winner is Lucas");
if(Simon.isAlive())
   System.out.println("winner is Simon");
```

Answer (score 2):

Make one class fighter and then 2 instances Fighter and Opponent ... I don't understand why you make 2 classes which are doing same job.

Answer (score 0):

Use getter and setter methods in both of the classes i.e Fighter and Opponent
Then

Your Fighter class looks like this

```
class Fighter{
private int punchStrength, movementSpeed, reflex;

    public int getPunchStrength() {
        return punchStrength;
    }

    public void setPunchStrength(int punchStrength) {
        this.punchStrength = punchStrength;
    }

    public int getMovementSpeed() {
        return movementSpeed;
    }

    public void setMovementSpeed(int movementSpeed) {
        this.movementSpeed = movementSpeed;
    }

    public int getReflex() {
        return reflex;
    }

    public void setReflex(int reflex) {
        this.reflex = reflex;
    }

    public Fighter(int punchStrength, int movementSpeed, int reflex) {

        this.punchStrength = punchStrength;
        this.movementSpeed = movementSpeed;
        this.reflex = reflex;
    }


}
```

Your Opponent class look like this

```
class Opponent{
        private int punchStrength, movementSpeed, reflex;

        public int getPunchStrength() {
            return punchStrength;
        }

        public void setPunchStrength(int punchStrength) {
            this.punchStrength = punchStrength;

    }

    public int getMovementSpeed() {
        return movementSpeed;
    }

    public void setMovementSpeed(int movementSpeed) {
        this.movementSpeed = movementSpeed;
    }

    public int getReflex() {
        return reflex;
    }

    public void setReflex(int reflex) {
        this.reflex = reflex;
    }

    public Opponent(int punchStrength, int movementSpeed, int reflex) {

        this.punchStrength = punchStrength;
        this.movementSpeed = movementSpeed;
        this.reflex = reflex;
    }


}
```

Now in your main class :

```
 Fighter Lucas = new Fighter (Statistics.punchStrength, 
Statistics.movementSpeed, Statistics.reflex);

 Opponent Simon = new Opponent (Statistics.punchStrength2, 
    Statistics.movementSpeed2, Statistics.reflex2);

int avgFighter = ((Lucas.getpunchStrength())+(Lucas.getmovementSpeed())+(Lucas.getreflex()))/3;

int avgOpponent = ((Opponent .getpunchStrength())+(Opponent .getmovementSpeed())+(Opponent .getreflex()))/3;

if(avgFighter > avgOpponent )
System.out.println("Fighter wins");
else if(avgFighter == avgOpponent)
System.out.println("Draw");
else
System.out.println("Fighter looses");
```

Comment: This is a bad advice. It violates the *information hiding* principle and will make the approach hard to maintain/extend.

Comment: I dont think so . as the member variables are not directly accessible without calling the getters ,so they are not violating the data hiding property. And any class can extend this basic functionality and can add its own

Comment: *"as the member variables are not directly accessible without calling the getters"* getters/setters **do provide** *direct access*.

Comment: "getters/setters do provide direct acces" but only through objects of that class,not directly .\

Comment: Your example shows clearly the disadvantage of getter/setter and how the *encapsulation* is violated. Your code *manipulates the internal state* of the objects from *outside the object*. This is called *feature envy* and is exactly what we want to avoid in OOP.

Comment: if this is a bad example, how should i do this properly? example that Vishesh has written works well

Answer (score 0):

## Short version

Make one class - `Fighter` - which has `fight(Fighter otherFighter)` method. In that method, resolve the fight, so that the `fight()` logic and `Fighter` implementation does not leak outside the class. For an example, see below.

## Long version

What I would do is abandon idea of having `Opponent` and `Fighter` classes if they're doing the same thing and have the same fields. Instead, why not have one `Fighter` class? The way I understand, the only difference between your objects is that they have different values - and that does not necessarily mean that you need to belong to different classes. Hence, unless `Fighter` can fight some other entities that have vastly different properties, one class should be enough. Besides, you can always extend the class if you need more fields or/and methods that behave slightly differently.

Now, determining who would win the fight is a rather interesting problem because you can do it in many ways, some more maintainable than others. On the one hand, you could calculate the outcome outside the classes. However, I do not think that this is the best approach. First of all, this means you need to know quite a lot about the `Fighter`, and how the fights work. Imagine if someone else worked with your code and wanted to resolve a fight. Would he/she be able to do it easily, or would he/she have to consult with you?

In my opinion, the logic should not leak to the outside, as this will make your code harder to maintain in the long run. E.g., what if attributes change? What if you want to resolve fights in multiple places of your code? Are you going to create a class whose sole purpose is to resolve a fight? Seems a bit strange. Or, worse yet, are you going to copy-paste the code? If so, what will you do if you need to change the logic of an outcome? Are you sure you can adjust *all* code you've copy-pasted? These are the questions you should be actively thinking about.

What I immediately think when I see a class named `Fighter` is that the entity represented, well, fights. Wouldn't it be nice if it could resolve the fights itself? Wouldn't it be logical place to put the code? Hence, my solution would be something like this:

```
public class Fighter {
    private int speed;
    private int reflex;
    private int strength;

    public Fighter(int speed, int reflex, int strength) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.reflex = reflex;
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public String fight(Fighter otherFighter) {
        int thisSum = speed + reflex + strength;
        int thatSum = otherFighter.speed + otherFighter.reflex + otherFighter.strength;
        int outcome = thisSum - thatSum;

        if (outcome == 0) {
            return "Draw";
        } else if (outcome > 0) {
            return "First fighter won";
        } else {
            return "Second fighter won";
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `fight()` method. You pass another `Fighter` instance into it and without any effort the fight is resolved. The only caveat is that you need a way to figure out to determine which attributes are 'higher' and calculate the overall outcome. There are many ways to do it, of course. I used `int`s for clarity and ease of use. But you could use anything you like, or implement any logic you want. In any case, now you can resolve the fight with one method call. Hence, the whole code *outside* the class looks something like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fighter fighter = new Fighter(1, 2, 3);
        Fighter opponent = new Fighter(4, 2, 1);
        System.out.println(fighter.fight(opponent));
    }
}
```

Naturally, `fight()` could be extended to contain much more complex logic. Or it could be changed to accept some common base class of opponents, monsters, or fighters, which would allow you not only to fight `Fighter`'s, but also other entities, too. Nevertheless, one thing I would try to achieve is to have as little logic about the fight as possible outside the `Fighter` class, so as to not have to change code in multiple places if I change my mind about how the fights work.

By the way, I have not used getters and setters, but it would probably be a good idea if getting an attribute involves some kind of logic.